# How do I decode call data in solidity?

Tags: solidity, abi, calldata, decoding, function-selector

I have data in memory that is used for a function call, so I guess that makes it [call data](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/internals/layout_in_calldata.html) rather than a [calldata (data location)](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/types.html?highlight=calldata#data-location). This call data, say `bytes memory data`, consists of a [selector and the encoding of the arguments](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/abi-spec.html#function-selector-and-argument-encoding). I would like to decode the data to retrieve its arguments. It does not seem to be possible.

For instance if `data` was encoded in this way:

```
string memory helloString = "hello";
bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(0x12345678, helloString);
```

how would I be able to retrieve the string "hello"? There is no `abi.decodeWithSelector`, or is there? For my use-case it would even be sufficient to just shift the entire data by 8 bytes to the left, but then `shl(n,data)` (assembly) doesn't work for reference types.

Comment: I've just seen that this seems to be a popular request https://groups.google.com/g/solidity-users/c/mVI3SbUHAq8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data was in calldata (data location) you could simply use [slices](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2020/05/26/array-slices/).
Unfortunately, slices are not available on memory arrays.

> how would I be able to retrieve the string "hello"? There is no
> abi.decodeWithSelector, or is there? For my use-case it would even be
> sufficient to just shift the entire data by 8 bytes to the left, but
> then shl(n,data) (assembly) doesn't work for reference types.

`shl` doesn't care about reference or value types, it just takes a value and shifts it. Your issue is that you didn't gave it the right value : `data` is a memory pointer, while you want to shift the actual data contained there.

Now you will need to do a bit more than just shifting if your data is more than 32 bytes long (which is always true with dynamic types such as `string` due to the way [abi encoding](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/abi-spec.html#contract-abi-specification) works).

To do so, you could use the following function, which works regardless of length, type or number of arguments :

```
function extractCalldata(bytes memory calldataWithSelector) internal pure returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory calldataWithoutSelector;

        require(calldataWithSelector.length >= 4);

        assembly {
            let totalLength := mload(calldataWithSelector)
            let targetLength := sub(totalLength, 4)
            calldataWithoutSelector := mload(0x40)
            
            // Set the length of callDataWithoutSelector (initial length - 4)
            mstore(calldataWithoutSelector, targetLength)

            // Mark the memory space taken for callDataWithoutSelector as allocated
            mstore(0x40, add(calldataWithoutSelector, add(0x20, targetLength)))


            // Process first 32 bytes (we only take the last 28 bytes)
            mstore(add(calldataWithoutSelector, 0x20), shl(0x20, mload(add(calldataWithSelector, 0x20))))

            // Process all other data by chunks of 32 bytes
            for { let i := 0x1C } lt(i, targetLength) { i := add(i, 0x20) } {
                mstore(add(add(calldataWithoutSelector, 0x20), i), mload(add(add(calldataWithSelector, 0x20), add(i, 0x04))))
            }
        }

        return calldataWithoutSelector;
    }
```

And call it to extract the part of interest :

```
function example() public pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory helloString = "hello";
        bytes memory dataWithSelector = abi.encodeWithSelector(0x12345678, helloString);
        return abi.decode(extractCalldata(dataWithSelector), (string));
    }
```

Which outputs `hello` as expected.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the encoded data by slicing the first 4 bytes of the calldata...
Remember, the first 4 bytes represents the function's signature, those bytes are not part of the actual data that you are interested on decoding.

You can refer to the answer on this question:
[**How to decode the msg.data on a function in plain solidity?**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144944/how-to-decode-the-msg-data-on-a-function-in-plain-solidity)

Basically the idea is:

```
abi.decode(msg.data[4:], (...));
```