# How to decode the msg.data on a function in plain solidity?

Tags: solidity, abi, calldata, decoding

I was wondering how to decode the data payload received on a function

At first, I thought it would be enough with knowing the order of the variables and the exact data type of them at the moment of encoding, but when I tried to decode the `msg.data` as follows `(var1,var2,var3) = abi.decode(msg.data,(dataType1,dataType2,dataType3));`, the operation was failing and the entire tx was reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging down on this topic, I found an interesting discussion about this exact same topic on Solidity's GitHub repository.(**https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/6012**)

Short long story, the reason why the `msg.data` can't be decoded is:

- The purpose of abi.decode is ABI decoding. **`msg.data` is not ABI encoded**, so it cannot be used there.

### Workaround

- As of the date of publishing this question (February 14th 2023), the suggested workaround is to slice the first 4 bytes of the `msg.data` which are the bytes of the function signature.

```
abi.decode(msg.data[4:], (...));
```

- The above workaround seems to make the trick and allows the msg.data to be decoded, of course, you need to follow the rules of abi.decode!

#### Example

##### Function sending msg.data to the decodeMsgData for further decoding

```
// Decodes the payload on the called function and returnes the decoded data!

function decodeMsgData_ExternalFunction(
    address to,
    uint256 value,
    address origSender
) public  returns (address _to, uint _value, address _origSender) {
    (_to, _value, _origSender) = decodeMsgData(msg.data);
}
```

##### Decoding function

```
// Decodes the msgData and returns the exact data that was encoded on the msgData!
    // address to,
    // uint256 value,
    // address origSender

function decodeMsgData(bytes calldata msgData) external pure returns (address to, uint value, address origSender) {
    // The first 4 bytes on the msgData are the function signature, in order to decode the payload it is required to skip those bytes of the function signature!
        // reference: "abi.decode cannot decode msg.data" <===> https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/6012
    (to, value, origSender) = abi.decode(msgData[4:],(address,uint,address));
}
```