# Extracting input data when writing Forge tests/POCs

Tags: solidity, testing, foundry, unittesting

I would like to write a test in Foundry but I need to be able to first read data from a previous transaction that was submitted in some point in the past.

For example, the transaction I'm interested in was to some contract, the function called in that transaction was to `deposit(address token, uint256 amount)`.

Is there a way for me to test:

1. submit a transaction that will be tracked
2. get that transaction's receipt/hash
3. I know the transaction function signature (i.e. `deposit(address,uint256)`), look at what arguments the transaction was sent with.
4. Arguments are what I expected, e.g. `AssertEq(arg1, expectedAddress)`, `AssertEq(arg2, expectedUint)`

This is for a POC I'm trying to write while learning Foundry and writing tests.

Comment: Don't have answer if it is exists natively, but foundry has ffi which means you can use any external command. I think you can use cast with ffi or your own solution to get data you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to a transaction that was included in previous blocks for a particular chain, you can get the transaction receipt using `cast` and decode the transaction data within the test itself (refer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/131283/how-do-i-decode-call-data-in-solidity)). This coupled with foundry `vm.ffi` will give you the test you need.
For Eg :
Here I have shown how to decode a simple ERC20 `transfer` transaction using cast within a forge test and then assert the decoded output.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CAL
pragma solidity =0.8.19; 
import {Test, console2} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract TransactionTest is Test {  
    // Decode transaction calldata with function selector
    function extractCalldata(bytes memory calldataWithSelector) internal pure returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory calldataWithoutSelector;
        require(calldataWithSelector.length >= 4);
        assembly {
            let totalLength := mload(calldataWithSelector)
            let targetLength := sub(totalLength, 4)
            calldataWithoutSelector := mload(0x40)
            
            // Set the length of callDataWithoutSelector (initial length - 4)
            mstore(calldataWithoutSelector, targetLength)

            // Mark the memory space taken for callDataWithoutSelector as allocated
            mstore(0x40, add(calldataWithoutSelector, add(0x20, targetLength)))

            // Process first 32 bytes (we only take the last 28 bytes)
            mstore(add(calldataWithoutSelector, 0x20), shl(0x20, mload(add(calldataWithSelector, 0x20))))

            // Process all other data by chunks of 32 bytes
            for { let i := 0x1C } lt(i, targetLength) { i := add(i, 0x20) } {
                mstore(add(add(calldataWithoutSelector, 0x20), i), mload(add(add(calldataWithSelector, 0x20), add(i, 0x04))))
            }
        }
        return calldataWithoutSelector;
    } 

    function testTransaction() public { 
        // Target Transaction to decode. (IERC20 transfer transaction)
        string memory txHash = "0xa88280fd1bedbb83b7e4260cda7c77e747eeacee199259b13607809cbffaeaf5";
        // Traget network rpc
        string memory rpcUrl = "https://1rpc.io/matic"; 
        // Cast command to get transaction data
        string memory castCommand = string.concat("cast tx ", txHash, " --rpc-url ", rpcUrl, " input ");

        string[] memory inputs = new string[](3);
        inputs[0] = "bash";
        inputs[1] = "-c";
        inputs[2] = castCommand;
        //Exec cast command
        bytes memory resultReceipt = vm.ffi(inputs);

        //Decode Data 
        (address to,uint256 amount) = abi.decode(extractCalldata(resultReceipt),(address,uint)); 
        assertEq(to,address(0x5A37E156191Befe6923765E20487Bad0a7057c28));
        assertEq(amount,5182246); 
    }
}
```